# JavaScript Multiple Toggle Navigation not working

Tags: javascript

Well my question is simple I have two navigation menu and I want toggle nav for both in mobile view my code is

```
 //Top Nav
 $(function() {  
var pull        = $('#pull');  
    menu        = $('#top-nav ul');  
    menuHeight  = menu.height();  

$(pull).on('click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();  
    menu.slideToggle();  
});  
 });

 $(window).resize(function(){  
    var w = $(window).width();  
if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {  
    menu.removeAttr('style');  
}  
 });
```

its working fine for a toggle but when I copy this code again and change IDs for nav menu it doesn't work both toggle buttons are opening second nav menu

```
 //Main Nav
 $(function() {  
var pull        = $('#pull-down');  
    menu        = $('#main-nav ul');  
    menuHeight  = menu.height();  

$(pull).on('click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();  
    menu.slideToggle();  
});  
 });
 $(window).resize(function(){  
var w = $(window).width();  
if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {  
    menu.removeAttr('style');  
}  
 });
```

any help?

Comment: Check in your HTML whether the IDs are given properly. id="pull" and id="pull-down"

Comment: yes it is properly given

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: here is the live link dotcomsourcing.com/projects/test/